ubuntu crash, no idea on how to solve it
I have rog flow x16 with ryzen 7 6800hs and rtx 3060, i have dual booted the system and have windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and kernel Linux 6.8.0-36-generic firmware GV601RM.318 the machine suddenly freezes and restarts and have problem when i close the lid of the laptop i log out but i might have to restart it happens every 2 out of 5 times i have tried searching but no success in solving the issue i have cheecked system logs and this line appears nearly hundred times
pcieport 0000:00:01.2: AER: Correctable error message received from 0000:06:00.0
2024-07-16T12:49:09.589607+05:30 shrey-ROG-Flow-X16-GV601RM-GV601RM kernel: nvme 0000:06:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
2024-07-16T12:49:09.589608+05:30 shrey-ROG-Flow-X16-GV601RM-GV601RM kernel: nvme 0000:06:00.0:   device [1344:5407] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
2024-07-16T12:49:09.589608+05:30 shrey-ROG-Flow-X16-GV601RM-GV601RM kernel: nvme 0000:06:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)

i have no idea what it says and would like some help
i have also installed asusctl before installing it the laptop would heat up badly and after installing and using it laptop stay moderately hot on touch of surface before it it would heat up and crash i dont have any idea why it happens
the device also has mux switch and i don't have any idea how to control it in this machine there is a toggle for it in asusctl and i dont know how it effects the machine
suggest me what should i do to prevent this from happening and make my machine  more stable.

In your question you make this statement. -have problem when i close the lid of the laptop - Please edit the question and add what the problem is.

How to solve NVME Issue.
This is a misconfiguration of hardware. There are 4 solutions offered.
By the rank of importance:

update bios.
Update firmware.
Add pcie_aspm=off to grub.
Add pci=noaer to grub. This is just a workaround, it hides the lines but the pci issue is present.


Source:
https://forums.unraid.net/topic/118286-nvme-drives-throwing-errors-filling-logs-instantly-how-to-resolve/

How to
add Parameters to Grub:
How do I add a kernel boot parameter?
